# Can't deploy django project on vercel

Tags: python, django, deployment, vercel

I am deploying a Django app on Vercel, but at the time of deployment the build_files.sh is not getting called

[image: Build output]
[image: Output after deployment]

vercel.json

```
{
    "builds": [{
            "src": "mysite/wsgi.py",
            "use": "@vercel/python",
            "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb", "runtime": "python3.9" }
        },
        {
            "src": "build_files.sh",
            "use": "@vercel/static-build",
            "config": { "distDir": "staticfiles_build" }
        }
    ],
    "routes": [{
            "src": "/static/(.*)",
            "dest": "/static/$1"
        },
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "mysite/wsgi.py"
        }
    ]
}
```

build_files.sh

```
 echo "BUILD START"
 python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
 python3.9 manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear
 echo "BUILD END"
```

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.